# django rest authentication return "don't include authentication information"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am making django authentication function via rest framework. I made view.py, serizlizers.py and backends.py. And I setup settings.py to call my own authentication function. 
But something is wrong and I got the error message that means "detail" : "don't include authentication information".

I have no idea what is wrong of my function. Please give me an advice.

```
backends.py

class RemoshinUserAuthBackend(BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):

        try:
            user = RemoshinUser.objects.get(username=username)
            if not user.check_password(password):
                return None
        except RemoshinUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        return user


    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

views.py

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class UserAuthenticationView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (RemoshinUserAuthBackend, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = RemoshinUserAuthInputSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': request.user.username,
            'auth': None,
        }
        return Response(content)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RemoshinUserAuthInputSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = authenticate(**serializer.data)
        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed()

        return Response(serializer.data)


serializers.py

class RemoshinUserAuthInputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RemoshinUser
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```